# How to tell TypeScript to allow multiple strings from a list, each, only once in a spread parameter?

Tags: typescript

I have a list of paramters that can be given to a function `'one' | 'two' | 'three' | 'four' | 'five'`. I want each to be used only once, like so:

```
function foo(...x: ('one' | 'two' | 'three' | 'four' | 'five')[]) {
  // do something...
}

foo('one', 'five', 'three', 'five'); // This works, even though I want TypeScript to say this isn't allowed.
```

Comment: You better accept a Set. It's a bit of a hack to leverage the type system to do this check. It will also be unenforceable for `foo(...userStrings)` unless you throw more code before calling this function only to appease the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment is correct: it will be nearly impossible to guarantee that only unique arrays will make it through, so no matter what you should have runtime code in place to de-duplicate any array passed in no matter what you do with the typing.

Still, you might want the typing to give users hints that you should only pass in each parameter type at most once.  This is possible and not even completely crazy with TypeScript 4.1's support for [recursive conditional types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40002):

```
type UniqueFrom<T extends any[], U> =
  U[] extends T ? T :
  T extends [infer F, ...infer R] ?
  [U, ...UniqueFrom<R, Exclude<U, F>>] : []

type Vals = 'one' | 'two' | 'three' | 'four' | 'five';

function foo<T extends Vals[]>(...t: UniqueFrom<T, Vals>) { }
```

The idea is that `UniqueFrom<T, Vals>` should produce a tuple of the same length as `T`, showing which elements from `Vals` are still available at each step as you walk through `T` from left to right.  for example:

```
type U = UniqueFrom<["one", "two", "three"], Vals>;
// [Vals, "two" | "three" | "four" | "five", "three" | "four" | "five"]
```

This says that the first element of `T` can be anything from `Vals`; once the first element is chosen to be `"one"`, now the next element can be anything from `Vals` except `"one"`.  When the second element is chosen to be `"two"`, now the last element can be anything from `"three"`, `"four"`, or `"five"`.

As long as `T` is assignable to `UniqueFrom<T, Vals>`, then the compiler will accept a tuple of type `T` as a rest argument to `foo()`.  Let's see if it works:

```
foo("one", "two", "three", "four", "five"); // okay
foo("two", "one", "six", "five"); // error! 
// -------------> ~~~~~
// type '"six"' is not assignable to type 'Vals'
foo("one", "two", "three", "two", "five"); // error!
// ----------------------> ~~~~~
// type '"two"' is not assignable to type '"four" | "five"'
```

This looks reasonable to me.  The compiler complains about a second parameter named `"two"`, and tells you that it was expecting either `"four"` or `"five"` there.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwM5QLxQOQHsB2ENQA+mwA7lgcRsABYBOE+RmAZlgK52WsCWAbvgDcAWABQY0JCgBVHD1wBROAGMaABTpYwSADwAVKBAAewCDgAmKODhABtALoAaWAD40UAN5RbAaSg8cKABrCBAsFig9ewAuSN97ZhgoAF8xCXBoAGVla31DEzNLKGs7ezd0A2NTCxRbAJYIOigAMWcAOg76xqgAJQSAfjEoGTlFFXVNbR1bPAE6do7s3J6XJxa3WIc00UloBSNlBHZzCA0tXUqCmuKbB2dpfOqikodyzyHvPwDg0PDImKgfiqhRQITCEQe-Sg+0Oxwg+ni93iGziPgSYlS4h2GSgAEEkLIeABHdjwy5PKy3MruGFHE5nKZ6ZwzCBzBZtJY4fSrFzbMRsLAACgARLgIMLnMKyFgJVApfRGLKpeRhQBKbYAeg1UBoAFtddtdiNiaTmppdXlgdcXmtpG9ySDvF0mq0oB02s7egMPrZ9sA6CpgDppM5mi52YSSRAzVgLT1nLS4cHQy5VlBNvZtix2DhlMB5IEBZarkV4MhXoL3cBYvjI6TuarPCkxEA)

Comment: This works excellent for a function, but how does it work with React Typescript properties?  I am trying to pass in to a React Component some things that I want hidden in the component, and I don't want to make a new prop for everything to hide.  When I try to implement this in a similar manner that you have with the function, it still allows multiple of the same value to be passed in.